# jupyter_server 2.0 seems to break showHiddenFiles in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab, hidden-files, jupyter-server

I am using JupyterLab with:

```
jupyterlab=3.5.1

jupyter_server=1.23.3
```

and I have the following config:

```
{
    // File Browser
    // @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:browser
    // File Browser settings.
    // *****************************************

    // Show hidden files
    // Whether to show hidden files
    "showHiddenFiles": true
}
```

as well as:

```
c.ContentsManager.allow_hidden = True
```

Everything is working fine and I can see all hidden files in the JupyterLab UI.

Now, if I just update jupyter server to the new version `jupyter_server=2.0.1`, I don't see anymore the hidden file (the config is the same).

Is there some incompatibility between jupyterlab and jupyter server for the hidden file or the config need to be done in a different way ?
It seems that jupyter server is causing some trouble with package like jupytext and other.

I am expecting the following:

[image: JupyterLab UI]

Comment: This is not expected. Would you mind creating a bug report in [jupyter-server](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/issues) repository? Even if there was an intentional change I don't see it in release logs and my expectation is that breaking changes should always be documented (speaking as contributor to jupyter-server and jupyterlab dev). If you don't use GitHub just let me know and I will create the issue.

Comment: Thanks and I will create an issue. I wanted to be sure I didn't miss some obvious update.

Comment: Here is the bug report, happy to provide more information if needed: https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/issues/1129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fixed and I am using now the following update tags :

```
jupyter_server 2.0.5
jupyter-core 5.1.1
(jupyterlab 3.5.2)
```

For more info you can look here: [ticket](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/issues/1129)